# react-scripts build heroku Web process failed to bind to $PORT issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, port, react-scripts

Have an issue running `react-scripts build` on a heroku-20 nodejs dyno

Heroku runs `npm start` which is

```
"prestart": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=prod node server/server"
```

and `client/package.json`

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build"
```

log:

```
2021-06-04T21:12:57.806280+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
2021-06-04T21:13:06.794538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-06-04T21:13:06.845028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-06-04T21:13:06.939986+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-06-04T21:13:07.001538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-04T21:13:10.445223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=...
```

On server.js, it has the following:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod'){
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.CLIENT_BASE); // domain of the incoming request
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
...
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

There are also some REACT_APP_ variables in `/client/.env` and in root `.env` for server-side variables. These are defined in Heroku dyno Settings, Config Vars

The expected result is heroku `react-script build` should generate a `build/` folder for client which is used by node server to serve static & CORS enabled as it works on local.
Actual result is heroku crashing see log

Comment: I changed `"prestart:"` to `"build:"` and it seemed to work. i think `prestart` was doing too much that exceed the 60s limit. `"start":` should be used to only execute code. `"heroku-postbuild":` is also an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved build scripts (react-scripts build) from `"start"` & `"prestart"` to either `"build"` or `"heroku-postbuild"` which resolved the issue. i think `"prestart:"` was doing too much that exceeded the heroku 60s port binding limit.
`"start":` should be used to only execute code